# Bisected median

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, solution-verification

In triangle $ABC$, let $D$ be the foot of the median from $C$. Let $F$ be the foot of the segment from $B$ such that $BF$ bisects $CD$, and $E$ be their point of intersection. If $CF=12$, find $AF$.

I used mass point geometry here. I let $AF = x$ and the mass of $C$ be $1$, then the mass of $A$ must be $\frac{12}{x}$, and so is point $B$. Adding the masses we get that point $D$ has mass $\frac{24}{x}$. Since $CD$ is bisected, the value of $x$ must be $24$. Is this correct?

Comment: If $F\in AC$ the answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ denote areas. Since CE = ED, We have $S_{CFB}=S_{DFB}$.  Then,
$$1=\frac{S_{DFB}}{S_{CFB}}
=\frac{\frac12 S_{ABF}}{\frac{CF}{AC}S_{ABC} }
=\frac{\frac12 \frac{AF}{AC}S_{ABC}}{\frac{CF}{AC}S_{ABC} }
=\frac{AF}{2CF}$$

Thus, AF = 2CF = 24.

Answer (score 0):

If $F\in AC$ your solution is right.

I like the following way.

Let $K\in AF$ such that $DK||BF.$

Thus, $$AK=KF=FC,$$ which gives
$$AF=12+12=24.$$